# Why is $\mathbb{Z}_n$ a field only if $n$ is prime?

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic

And $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the set of residue classes modulo $n$.

Comment: You need inverses in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for it to be a field, but you're only guaranteed inverses if you have every element coprime to $n$, which happens when $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is composite say $n=ab$ then we get $[a][b]=[n]=[0]$ ; $[a],[b]\neq [0]$;hence not even an Integral Domain

Comment: What about $n=1$? ;-)

Comment: The modulo classes are irrelevant to discuss for $n=1$@quid

Comment: @learnmore technically not true.  Really, $\Bbb Z_1 = \{[0]\}$, which is (isomorphic to) the trivial ring and therefore a field.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom did you mean to say "not a field" or do you have a different convention for what a field is? (To me in a field $1 \neq 0$ must hold.)

Comment: @quid I just forgot what the usual convention is. I believe you, though

Comment: How is $\Bbb Z_1=[0]$@Omnomnomnom;$\Bbb Z_1=\Bbb Z$ In $\Bbb Z_n$ we take each element of $\Bbb Z$ modulo $n$ ;what happens if $n=1$

Comment: The classes modulo $n$ are in correspondence with the remainders upon division by $n$. For $n=1$ we divide by $1$ this always leaves remainder $0$. Or,  $0$  modulo $n$ is the set of all integers of the form $0 + n \mathbb{Z}$. For $n=1$ this are all integers, thus there is only one class modulo $1$. Or, $a$ and $b$ are congruent modulo $n$ if $n$ divides $a-b$. For $n=1$ it is always true that $n$ divides $a-b$. Or, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the quotient ring of $ \mathbb{Z}$ by the ideal $n \mathbb{Z}$. For $n=1$, we have $n \mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial ring.

Comment: It is not common to write it like this, but if anything $\mathbb{Z}_0$ would be (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Z}$. (The argument with division breaks down, but the other three arguments I gave work, and yield this.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $[a] \in \Bbb Z_n$ denote the residue class of $a \in \Bbb Z$. In order for $\Bbb Z_n$ to be a field, all non-zero elements must have multiplicative inverses. That is, we must be able to say that for every $a$ with $[a] \neq [0]$, there exists an $x \in \Bbb Z$ such that $[a][x] = [1]$.

In other words: for every $a$ with $n \nmid a$, the equation $ax \equiv 1 \pmod n$ must have a solution $x \in \Bbb Z$.  That is, the equation $ax = 1 + ny$ must have a solution with $x,y \in \Bbb Z$.  That is, there must exist $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ such that
$$
ax - ny = 1
$$
whenever $n \nmid a$. By [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), this is equivalent to saying that $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ whenever $n \nmid a$.  That is, $\Bbb Z_n$ is a field if and only if $n$ is prime.